# Why the double free on string operator=?

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks, stl, queue

I am using g++ and mudflap.  When I run my code, it aborts where mudflap complaining about a double free:

```
*** glibc detected *** /mydir/MYMain: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000002127880 ***
```

If I run it in gdb, I can see where it aborts:

```
queue<string> logQueue;
void someThreadSpawnFunction() {
    string str;
    while(true) {
       {
           boost::scoped_lock sl( aMutex);
           // thread wait for loqQueue to have item
           str = logQueue.front();    // <---------------    Aborts here.
           logQueue.pop();
       }
       //write out string
}
```

**The question is:** Am I using std::queue and strings incorrectly?

In other parts of the code, there will be something like:

```
string msg;
// processMessage            -- some bit a of code with stripNull()
logQueue.push(msg);
```

The only funny thing I can find in processMessage is this function:

```
std::string Log::stripNull(const std::string &str, bool &gotNulls)
{
    std::string retStr = str;

    // strip any trailing NULLs
    size_t rsltPos = retStr.find_first_of('\0', 0);
    if (rsltPos != string::npos)
    {
        gotNulls = true;
        retStr.resize(rsltPos);
    }
    return(retStr);
}
```

Is it possible mudflap may be complaining about the stripNull function?

Thanks.

Comment: Typically, when you get this error, it's not because your current operation is "wrong"< but because something else has gone wrong earlier - e.g. you've overwritten the boundaries of an array or freed something twice in another piece of the code. Unfortunately, the library only detects it when it tries to use the field next time.

Comment: Acquiring a mutex cannot by itself guarantee that your queue is not empty. If you try to take an element from an empty queue, you may see a crash just like this one.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to check that there is actually a string to obtain.

When the queue is empty and you perform `.front()`, if you're unlucky you may *just so happen* to get a sort of "ghost" version of whatever used to be the first element in the queue.

Then, when you're attempting to `.pop()` a non-existent object, you're indirectly invoking the destructor on that "ghost". The original object was already destroyed, hence the double-free.

Comment: In the mutexed block, I wait for the queue to have an item.  I used a comment for it, though, because I didn't want to clutter the example. Anyways, good suggestion, perhaps waiting for queue to fill could be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect a race condition. That mutex may not be enough.